# Dynamics CRM Oauth token expiring fast

Tags: oauth, dynamics-crm

We are using OAuth to get Access Token and Refresh Token. But  Access Token is getting expired fast.We need token with long validity.
How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dynamics CRM, Access tokens are expired in 3600sec. But refresh token will not expire. So you need to generate the new
accesstoken using the refresh token.

If you want refer below page, It will useful for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn645542(v=azure.100)